# Why do I get TypeError: IceCreamDebugger.configureOutput() got an unexpected keyword argument 'contextAbsPath'?

Tags: python, typeerror, keyword

I installed:

> pip list | grep icecream
> icecream                 2.1.2

I tried:

```
>>> from icecream import ic 
>>> ic.configureOutput(contextAbsPath=True)
```

I got:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: IceCreamDebugger.configureOutput() got an unexpected keyword argument '**contextAbsPath**'

So the [Icecream documentation](https://github.com/gruns/icecream) suggest this setting, I don't understand, why I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as you and installed icecream in version 2.1.2. When you take a look into the function's parameter names you see that the parameter `contextAbsPath` is not there:

[image]

Very strange, maybe there is a deviation between the wiki and the current code base?

When you download the Source code zip (version 2.1.2) from [GitHub](https://github.com/gruns/icecream/archive/refs/tags/v2.1.2.zip) you can see it right away in your editor:

[image]